# JQUERY datepicker calendar, how can I rename the "done" button to "close"

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, calendar, datepicker

How can i rename the Done button text to "Close", the code as follows,

```
jQuery("#fromDatepicker, #toDatepicker").datepicker({

    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth : true,
    changeYear : true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',     
});
```

the above code displays JQuery datepicker calendar, Done button is present in Button Panel,
i would like to change the "Done" text to "Close". Please any one help me.

Answer (score 10):

You should add the `closeText` option to your call.

```
jQuery("#fromDatepicker, #toDatepicker").datepicker({

    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth : true,
    changeYear : true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    closeText : "Close"
});
```

Comment: @Ravichandra: please consider the comment I've left at the bottom of your question. Stackoverflow does have some rules and never accepting answers is very rude around here. Please have a look at the links I gave you and please ask if there is something you still don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

Provide `closeText: "close"`

or

`$("#fromDatepicker, #toDatepicker").datepicker("option", "closeText", "close");`

Comment: Thank you very much, it saved me a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

add Close Text: for example change it to clear

closeText: 'Clear'

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#fromDatepicker, #toDatepicker").datepicker("option", "closeText", "close");
```